# UDF JavaScript implementation into Snowflake

Tags: javascript, sql, database, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I found usefull JS function that I want to implement into snowflake's UDF in order to move complex computation to the dwh.

http://trentrichardson.com/2010/04/06/compute-linear-regressions-in-javascript/

Attempt to rework above as SQL procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE JS_LNR_REG(a array, b array)
RETURNS ARRAY
LANGUAGE javascript
AS
$$
function linearRegression(y,x){
var lr = {};
var n = y.length;
var sum_x = 0;
var sum_y = 0;
var sum_xy = 0;
var sum_xx = 0;
var sum_yy = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {

    sum_x += x[i];
    sum_y += y[i];
    sum_xy += (x[i]*y[i]);
    sum_xx += (x[i]*x[i]);
    sum_yy += (y[i]*y[i]);
} 

lr['slope'] = (n * sum_xy - sum_x * sum_y) / (n*sum_xx - sum_x * sum_x);
lr['intercept'] = (sum_y - lr.slope * sum_x)/n;

return lr;}      ; $$;
```

Execution fails with error: `SQL compilation error: Invalid identifier` which is odd since procedure has been created.

```
SELECT JS_LNR_REG('[2,4,5,3,1]', '[5.2, 5.7, 5.0, 4.2]');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.  To pass an array, try using ARRAY_CONSTRUCT or PARSE_JSON, like so:

```
SELECT JS_LNR_REG(array_construct(1,2,3,4), array_construct(5,4,3,2));
SELECT JS_LNR_REG(parse_json('[1,2,3,4]'), parse_json('[5,4,3,2]'));
```

To get the code working, make it a FUNCTION that returns OBJECT, and be sure to actually invoke linearRegression() from within your UDF:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION JS_LNR_REG(A array, B array)
  RETURNS OBJECT
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  STRICT
AS
$$
function linearRegression(y,x){
  var lr = {};
  var n = y.length;
  var sum_x = 0;
  var sum_y = 0;
  var sum_xy = 0;
  var sum_xx = 0;
  var sum_yy = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {

      sum_x += x[i];
      sum_y += y[i];
      sum_xy += (x[i]*y[i]);
      sum_xx += (x[i]*x[i]);
      sum_yy += (y[i]*y[i]);
  } 

  lr['slope'] = (n * sum_xy - sum_x * sum_y) / (n*sum_xx - sum_x * sum_x);
  lr['intercept'] = (sum_y - lr.slope * sum_x)/n;

  return lr;
  }      

  return linearRegression(A,B)
; $$;
```

Hope that's helpful.

Comment: Would `return linearRegression(A,B)` work as positional parameter?

Comment: A and B are positional parameters in the call to lineanRegression(), is that what you mean?

Comment: I reparaphrase ;) `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION JS_LNR_REG(A array, B array)`. How A and B in CREATE statement know to pass these arrays into `return linearRegression(A,B)`

Comment: Ah yes, they are indeed positional.

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake natively supports [REGR_INTERCEPT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regr_intercept.html) and [REGR_SLOPE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regr_slope.html) functions:

Input as arrays:

```
SELECT REGR_SLOPE(f2.value, f1.value) AS slope
      ,REGR_INTERCEPT(f2.value, f1.value) AS intercept 
FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(input => parse_json('[2,4,5,3]'))) AS f1
    ,TABLE(FLATTEN(input => parse_json('[5.2, 5.7, 5.0, 4.2]'))) AS f2
WHERE f1.INDEX = f2.INDEX;
-- slope    intercept
-- 0.09      4.71
```

Input as table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(x NUMBER(18,2), y NUMBER(18,2));
INSERT INTO tab(x, y) VALUES (2,5.2), (4, 5.7), (5, 5.0),(3, 4.2);

SELECT REGR_SLOPE(y, x) AS slope, REGR_INTERCEPT(y, x) AS intercept
FROM tab;
-- slope    intercept
-- 0.09      4.71
```